# jScrollPane on mobile browsers reacts slowly?

Tags: jquery, mobile-website, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

Hey there- I've been working on a mobile web project that has me using jScrollPane.  Keep in mind that I set the bg graphics to fixed and overflow to hidden, which essentially removes the native viewport scrollbars. Anyway, when I apply a jScrollPane to a div containing overlapping text, the jScrollPane works, but not very quickly.  Is there maybe a way to tweak it for mobile browsers?  Thanks!

Comment: which mobile/device/browser is this? did you test it on other devices?

Comment: Android, iPhone/iPad and BlackBerry 6 phones.  They all seems to run it slowly unforunately.